# Can you use search engines when doing an assessment at interview?

Tags: interviewing

I admit that I spend most of my time googling for a solution when faced with a problem.
So, when it comes to interviewing, sometimes the question is really tough or there are questions you never tried before.

I understand this is to assess how much do we understand about theory but sometimes I also wondering, perhaps interviewer wants to know how are we going to solve the problem?

I am struggling with this question, with regards to a developer role:

**Am I allowed to use search engines when doing an interview assessment**?

Comment: Are you talking about live interviews? Because, for assessments you complete in your own time, they shouldn't be able to tell that you used Google, because you shouldn't be copying significant parts of your solution nor anything you can't explain.

Comment: What kind of assessment this is?

Comment: Be aware that we check browser history after an interview so we know what candidates googled. If they googled incredibly simple things it is a bad sign. If you have time it is good to delete your history and then do some complex searches like nuclear fusion etc.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga You don't pass the interview.  Can audit pages visited without using browser history as they are using your network.

Comment: @Dukeling we like to leave them alone while doing the task and not put pressure by sitting next to them. We however ask them at the end some questions and to explain why they've done it like that.

Comment: @paparazzo maybe in big companies it is like that, but we use the building's wifi, we don't control the network.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga You don't have your own Internet and you are attempting a controlled computer based assessment and leave the WIFI activated?  Wow

Comment: @paparazzo what's wrong with that? we want the users to search the internet as it is part of the job. but we are curious what they searched for as we can gain valuable insight about them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whether you're allowed to use external sources will be up to the ones evaluating you.

The question itself is entirely fair as it merely draws up the boundaries of the task.

Personally, I would ask whether it is OK to use StackOverflow rather than Google (even though I generally use Google and end up following a link to StackOverflow), as it signals you have a go-to place when solving problems and are not just arbitrarily searching (even though you are).

Comment: Hi @morsor
Thank you for your answer.

Sometimes I feel like asking if I am allowed to use an external source but it seems like a behavior that lack of confidence?

Comment: It depends on the situation, (corporate) culture and the exact role being sought after. Not using external sources seems like an exam to me, whereas using them more closely resembles the way one actually performs tasks. In the early stages of hiring, some employers  tend to use quick exam-like questions to attempt to weed out unqualified candidates. However, the further ahead in the process, they tend to prefer tests that more closely mirror everyday tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Your potential employer is very likely interested in having you correctly completing the assigned tasks in a given time.

That you already knew how to handle it or that you searched for help it has little impact on the outcome, as long as you can be on schedule.

Someone said that knowledge is not about keeping all the information in your head, but knowing where to find it when it is needed. This is the very case.

Comment: Thank you for helping out to edit.
I strongly agree with your statement. XD

Comment: Someone also said, "give me google, stackoverflow, Ctrl-c, Ctrl-v and I can code anything" :-P

Comment: @ChatterOne,

Well, from my point of view, It has no harm for doing so because this is how you solve your problem. I just want to get the thing done and not really care how you copy and paste or you do it from scratch.

* Of course * if the company want to know how to solve your problem usually. :P

Comment: That heavily depends on what the company is looking for. If they just want someone that can write code, they can pretty much hire almost any 15 years old nowadays. If they want someone that actually understands what he/she's doing and maybe grow into another role, (let's say software architect for example), they'll probably expect you to be able to come up with solutions, not having someone else giving them to you.

Comment: @ChatterOne as a senior tech lead engineer, I admit my "coming up with solutions" usually involves **heaps** of browsing blogs, documentation, stack overflow and general googling: I feel like a brain-dead potato without that.

Comment: @ChatterOne, before the era of internet engineers had widely available handbooks giving all the formulas they might need. No engineer was shamed for consulting an handbook.

Comment: @L.Dutch As I said, the problem is not in using the resources that you have available (anyone can do that), but in understanding what those resources mean. If you limit yourself to copy and paste, you'll suck as a developer/engineer. If you make the effort to understand what you read, you'll grow as a professional.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have *Google* in performing the job then it seems reasonable to use *Google* for the assessment. But it should still be your own work. Don't copy solutions as a whole. If the assessment does not match your real skills it will eventually come out. If it lands you a job you are not qualified for you will be frustrated and possibly fired.

Take it to an extreme.  Does refer to the documentation count as cheating?  If they want a controlled result then they should have timed tasks at their location with either no access to the Internet or limited (E.G. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us). This is just my opinion but I think is should be like 8 super easy questions if you miss you are out. And then 1 or 2 challenging questions in 2-4 hours. A two week take home to build a full web site to me is ridiculous - that is a company that has no idea how to measure core skills.

I see tech questions that appear to be interview question and I will typically pass unless the question is interesting to me.

If you are going to post for an answer on the stack exchange network then use a name that does not trace back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general rule for this unfortunately, some interviews may be on a computer with access to the internet and they may be fine with you searching online, some may ask you to solve on a whiteboard in front of them, and then there's a million variations in between.

So instead of trying to suggest whether it's OK to use google or not, I feel the answer you actually need is to know **what you can do when you can't use your normal tools** (i.e. when you are restricted to just your memory).

I'd suggest the following for best communicating your skills:

- For problems you can solve directly, solve them first.
- If you believe there is a better way, make this clear. If this relies on some knowledge you don't know off the top of your head - detail why you think there's a better way, and what you what specific things you need to double check. For example: "I think we can improve this using `x`, but I'm not sure if `y` behaves like this or not - I'd need to check this first".
- If you only know how to partially solve a problem, abstract the areas you can't solve and then proceed to solve the problem with those assumptions detailed. For example, "We need to get `a` to work with `b`, I'm not sure exactly how we'd do that - so I'd need to check up on it first - but after that, it would allow `c` to do this that and the other".
- If you don't know how to solve it at all, detail similar problems that you have solved before and how these relate to your current problem. Give ideas on what you think you'd need to look into. "I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but it looks similar to `y` I've worked on before. My gut instinct is part of it can be solved by something similar to `z` - which I think we could look into".

The key with all of these is to never give no-answer. Even the questions you are completely stumped by, you should be answering how you would go about getting the specific information you need and what exactly you are unsure of.

There's no way to know what tools you will or will not be allowed to use in a certain interview, nor is there a way to guess what an employer is looking for in your solutions. But if you give as much detail on what parts you don't understand as possible, you'll be able to show your skills and experience to their fullest.